# How to delete item ID from array used as session shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a SESSION['cart'] with ID numbers only. I have a form passing the ID with a remove button. Once passed to my controller, I cannot figure out how to write the code that uses the ID ($_POST['id']) to delete the item from the SESSION['cart'].

I can loop through and display the array contents, but I cannot figure out how to delete based on ID passed from the form.

How do I loop through the SESSION['cart'] array to find a match with the ID passed from my delete form, and then delete that ID? I know that unset($_SESSION['cart'][X] deletes the ID at index X, but I cannot figure out how to loop through all the elements to find a match.

I have read a number of related issues in this forum but have been unable to apply any of those solutions to resolve this challenge. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: As a side remark, you do have a cart variable that is only storing the articles id ? I'm quite sure you would at least need a quantity...

Comment: Thank you. Quantity is not included, but I do plan to add it after I resolve this challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to do it right:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$items = $_SESSION["cart"];
if(($key = array_search($id, $items)) !== false) {
    unset($items[$key]);
}
$_SESSION["cart"] = array_values($items);
```

### Advice

Beside item ID, you can also sve item count in SESSION array because user can add several times same item into cart. In that case your $_SESSION["card"] should be structured like:

```
array(
    '1'=>12,//Item with ID=1 is added 12 times in shopping cart
    '17'=>2,//Item with ID=17 is added 2 times in shopping cart etc.
    '32'=>12,
)
```

Comment: Thank you MrD!  I interpreted the application of your solution as the following:   
    $id = $_POST['id']; // get the id from the form
    $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if ( isset($items[$id] ) ) {
        unset($items[$id]);
        $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
    }
If I did not make an error, it did not remove the item. Here is the var_dump of the SESSION['cart'] with three items: array (size=3)
  0 => string '181' (length=3)
  1 => string '33' (length=2)
  2 => string '34' (length=2)  Am I correct that to delete ID 181 is to delete $_SESSION['cart'][0] and not $_SESSION['cart'][181]?

Comment: You are the man MrD! It works perfectly! I will study this to learn precisely how it works. My next challenge is quantity changes. I will read up on array_search() at php.net. Thank you very much for taking the time to help. Thank you MrD!

Comment: No problem man Im glad thet I helped. If your problem is resolved, and my answer is right, just mark it then as correct ;)

Comment: As this is the marked answer and people often stop reading: While the solution works, this isn't the way to go. Follow the 'Advice' part of the post, or check out my answer. MrD and me didn;t come up with this for no reason ;)

Answer (score 2):

The way you have your values (`$products = array(3,7,99,152)`) isn't a very good method. **Every time you want to perform an action, you have to loop through the array, *you don't want that***. Apart from that, how do you store quantity? Or variations like e.g. size or color?

if your structure is `$array[ ID_OF_PRODUCT ]`, you can simply do this:

```
unset( $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']] ); // Instant access via the key!
```

---

**This should be the method to use**. This allows you to create an array like this, with advanced info, but with easy access (42/63 are example id's)

```
$_SESSION['cart']['products'][42] = array(
    'quantity' = 11,
    'size'     = 'large',
    'color'    = 'blue'
);
$_SESSION['cart']['products'][63] = array(
    'quantity' = 9,
    'size'     = 'small',
    'color'    = 'red'
);
```

This way you can access a lot of info with the product ID, and now also see which size and color (both just examples) the user selected. **You may not have need for this now, but you will further down the road :)**
As you might see, you can easily do stuff with the item:

```
isset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]); // check if the product exists
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]); // remove the product
echo $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]['quantity']; // get the quantity.
```

Not a loop in the code. You should only use loops when you have to, try to somewhat avoid them because often their slow. Say you have an extreme case of 1000 items in your shop, and you need to delete no999... That'll take a noticable moment.

Comment: Thanks Martinjn! I apologize for my example being unclear. I really want to grasp this fully. I did the following, but item 181 did not unset: 
$cart = array (181,33,129,34);
var_dump($cart);

unset($cart[181]);
var_dump($cart);
Then, I did this, and it did unset. Please help me understand more. 
$cart = array (181,33,129,34);
var_dump($cart);

unset($cart[0]);
var_dump($cart);

Comment: Is 42 the ID for this particular product?

Comment: Yes, 42 is an example id for a product. As you can see, I use the ID as value.

Comment: I strongly suggest you update your code. You may not see this now, but this will be A LOT EASIER in the long run

Comment: I am committed to doing it the best way, so thank you for your input. What you describe is reasonable and succinct. I like the flexibility also. I do not know how to create such an array. I tried and appear close. Is it appropriate in this forum for me to paste additional code in this box? Do yo want to see it? The project is helicopter parts and to get ID numbers via email to the client to match against the database and prepare a quote. It evolved into a shopping cart, etc. I like avoiding loops and maximizing the use of the ID to check if it exists and to remove and/or edit. Please advise

Comment: This is not a forum type of site, and posting your code as comment will not be pretty (as it's not made for code). I suggest you play around a bit and if you really can't find a solution, you post another question. The larger codeblock in my answer is how you set products

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again Martinjn!

Comment: I spent the entire day trying to figure this out.  Can you recommend a book or article that I can read to understand how this works?

Comment: It is called a *multidimentional array*, first thing I've found as this: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php

Comment: Thanks Martinjn. I will check it out. I had a breakthrough today based on your first reply. I wrote some code that I'm proud of and posted a challenge I encountered: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354221/stop-null-submission-and-display-message-near-form)